# Use Euler's theorem to get $3^{3^{3^{3^{3^{3}}}}}\ldots \pmod{100}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I'm supposed to use the nested Euler's theorem to get $3^{3^{3^{3^{3^{3}}}}}\ldots \pmod{100}$ where there are 2021 3's.

I've tried two approaches $3^{27} = 27^9 = 27*27^8 = 27*(729)^4 \equiv 27*29^4$ and got to the point where I found $3^{3^3}\equiv 87$. But I'm not using Euler's theorem here, nor am I able to stretch this to extend the case where I have 2021 3's.

Another approach is writing down the totient functions. $\phi(100) = 40 ,\phi(40) = 16, \phi(16) = 8, \phi(8) = 4, \phi(4) = 2, \phi(2) = 1$.

In any case, I'm stuck and not sure where I can proceed from here. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Euler's theorem says $3^{87}\equiv3^7=2187$

Comment: I see - but how do I expand it to 2021 3's?

Answer (score 4):

To find $3\uparrow2021$ mod $100$, Euler's theorem says you basically just need to know what is $3\uparrow2020$ mod $\phi(100)=40$.

To find $3\uparrow2020$ mod $40$, Euler's theorem says you basically just need to know what is $3\uparrow2019$ mod $\phi(40)=16$.

Do you see where this is going? Eventually it will be mod $2$, and the tall power of $3$ is odd so you will know that value is $1$. And then you can work backwards.